# How do I model a set of unique codes in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I have to store a list of unique sorted codes in Cassandra. 
Once it is read, it needs to be discarded. Every time I read this table, a new code needs to be returned.

How do I model this ?

I tried adding this code to a clustering key, buti don't quite know how to discard it so my next query will not return it.

Setting a short ttl still results the code being returned in my select

Comment: Are you thinking of a queue?

Comment: Not a queue. I just gave a unique set of codes that happen to be sorted. I don't really care much about the Oder. I just want to use them one by one. I have to use Cassandra, no other option

Comment: In such a parallel system as cassandra you will have a hard time. If you can control fully the client that accesses cassandra you can use a high consistency level as ALL or QUORUM and serialize all reads and updates.

Comment: Cassandra's CQL collections provides a Set data type that you should be able to use for this purpose. (By definition, a set is a collection of unique objects.) You can remove the code from the set after it is read.